# Apache multiple VirtualHost with same ServerName, same IP and Port but different DocumentRoot, possible?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

Besides its business purpose, my web application has an administration (e.g. myapp.com/admin/index.php) page and other stuff (e.g. myapp.com/other/index.php) too.

These pages don't need to be available all the time, let's just say that they "turn off" 10 minutes after Apache has started.

I cannot use another ServerName, nor can I use different IP and Port for these VirtualHosts. I don't want any weird workaround such as moving the index.php files somewhere else and also I can't use .htaccess. I need to use **a2ensite** or **a2dissite**.

Edit: my web application uses HTTPS only.

It is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not, because of how apache determines the `VirtualHost` for a request.

This is what the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html#namebased) says (emphasis mine):

> If the request contains a Host: header field, the list is searched for
>   the **first** vhost with a matching ServerName or ServerAlias, and the
>   request is served from that vhost.

If you try, you will get some warning along this lines:

```
[warn] VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
```